# How to run the SuiteTest many times in testNG file

Tags: java, selenium, testng

How to run the same set of tests many times use testNG.
I want to run one class with a few test (@Test) many times via Jenkins.
I want to create parametres in Jenkins with number tests to run.

XML file name: SmokeTests

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

 <suite name="testNG_SmokeTesty" >
     <test name="Products Module">
         <classes>
             <class name="Products" />
         </classes>
     </test>
 </suite>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987743/repeat-build-n-times-in-jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Please use invocationCount in @Test, so that while you run the test case through testng XML, that testcase will be executed that many time.

Example: 
@Test (invocationCount =3)
public void testMethod(){

}

this "testMethod" will be executed three times.